# GAE Namespace with Spring MVC + Spring Security + Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, spring-security, google-cloud-datastore

How to setup Google namespace filter with Spring Security?
I want to set the namespace once user is logged-in using user id.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException{

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(authentication.isAuthenticated())
    {
        User currentUser = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        NamespaceManager.set(currentUser.getId().toString());
    }
    else{
        NamespaceManager.set("");
    }
    chain.doFilter(req,res);
}
```

current web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>NamespaceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.etailerp.security.NamespaceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NamespaceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

current application.xml

```
 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/errors/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login login-page="/" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=true"/>   
    <logout logout-success-url="/"/>
    <custom-filter ref="namespaceFilter" before="FIRST" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security documentation states:

> You can also use the after or before attributes if you want your filter to be inserted before or after another filter in the stack. The names "FIRST" and "LAST" can be used with the position attribute to indicate that you want your filter to appear before or after the entire stack, respectively.

From my point of view using `FIRST` as a value of attribute `before` is illegal. I would suggest avoiding adding such a functionality via filter and rather use e.g. custom `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler` implementation for that purpose.